# Textual UseCase Representaion and graph generation

Tags: eclipse, uml, use-case

I am searching for a textual representation on UseCases which allows me to generate the graphs afterwards. Is there a tool, preferred open-source or freeware,  or an eclipse plugin out there, which allows doing that?

I found a [blog post](http://www.virage-it.be/2010/10/first-m2m-and-m2t-applications/) on an xText DSL example for doing that magic, but it is not working anymore, so maybe there is more active development somewhere, or someone maybe fixed this already for newer eclipse version?

[image: xText DSL Use Case Example]

Comment: I am working on something like that, but nothing working on current version of Xtext yet. The syntax can be greatly improved from that blog post and I use metauml (through TeXlipse) for rendering the diagrams and documentation.

Comment: Well let me know if you are going to publish that, so I could even participate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also enter all this information in the usecase at model level and then manually create your usecase diagram.
[alt text http://www.forum-omondo.com/download/file.php?id=253&mode=view](http://www.forum-omondo.com/download/file.php?id=253&mode=view)

Comment: Probably it would be clever to combine that with  M2M and M2T and use xText to make it work, but it would need some work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at yuml.me , an online service that renders for you UML diagrams based on textual definitions